# Struts The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, html, xml, eclipse, struts

Using Servlet 3.0, Maven 4.0, JDK 8 with compliance 1.8.
I don't know if the problem is due to eclipse not being able to build the project against the libraries correctly, or if it's tomcat. It may be a permission issue, despite the fact that i'm running both tomcat and eclipse as root, but who knows. At this point i'm starting to run out of ideas.

[Libs Imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7RGR.png)

The index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Page d'Acceuil</title>
</head>
<body>
    <html:form action="/ajouter">
        <table border="1">
            <caption>Gestion des etudiants STRUTS 1</caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Nom:<input type="text" name="nom"/></td>
                <td>Prenom:<input type="text" name="prenom"/></td>
                <td>Cin:<input type="text" name="cin" /></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Recherche Etudiant" onclick="recherche()"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Ajouter Etudiant" onclick="ajout()"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Supprimer Etudiant" onclick="sup()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </html:form>
</body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajout(){
                this.document.forms[0].action="ajouter.do";
                this.document.forms[0].submit();
            }
            function recherche(){
                this.document.forms[0].action="rechercher.do";
                this.document.forms[0].submit();
            }
            function sup(){
                this.document.forms[0].action="supprimer.do";
                this.document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

My index.jsp requests leads to either this error :

```
    Type Exception Report

Message The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:250)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:421)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:479)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:358)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:338)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:325)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:580)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Or this one :

```
    Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

My web.xml is as following, as you can see even if i supposedly shouldn't be adding these taglibs in there since i'm using servlet 3.0, i'm still declaring them just in case.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Etudiant</display-name>

  <!-- Servlet controleur de Struts -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Mapping des url avec la servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- page d'accueil de l'application -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <jsp-config>
  <taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-html
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

My deployment assembly and java build path are also updated correctly to include those libs, but none of this seems to solution the problem.

If you have any idea, i would gladly look into it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the whitespace around the URI and location values?

Comment: Yes i tried, but didn't change anything

Comment: Which version of Struts is this? What happens if you remove the standalone TLD files and declarations from the web.xml?

Comment: Sorry i should've added it's struts 1.3, and same error when i remove TLD both from declaration and  WEB-INF folder

Comment: Which version of Tomcat is it? Have you checked the deployed web app location and verified that the jars are there?

Comment: I tried running this with tomcat 8 and 7. Same error. Concerning the deployment resssources i looked into deployment assembly under properties and deployed ressources  but the jars seems to be there indeed.

Comment: How are you running Tomcat? You mention the deployment assembly, but I see a pom. Are the struts artifacts declared in the pom?

Comment: I'm running Tomcat in terminal as root, and i've declared the three required artifacts for struts : javax.servlet-api 3.1.0, struts-core 1.3.10, struts-taglib 1.3.10 in my pom. I've changed the nature of the project to maven recently, but the error existed also before this change. Also an interesting side note : when i right click project through eclipse and click run as server, i get a 404 error page, but when i run the server from eclipse (by rightclicking run on the servers tab) it shows the same error than when i run it from terminal (500 internal). Any idea on this particular behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION :

I've managed to resolve this problem by following these steps :

1) Remove all the tlds. and struts jars from lib.

2) Convert the project to maven nature

3) Have the following dependencies added to the pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

4) Use the corresponding struts configuration dtd in struts-config header, for me it was the following since i was using Struts 1.3 :

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
```

5) Make sure the action(s) bracket(s) syntax is correct :

```
<action path="/ajouter" input="/index.jsp" name="myFormBean"
         type="org.your.pckg.src.MyServletAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/redirection_page.jsp" />
        </action>
```

And that's pretty much it, you may also have to change your java compliance as i had to downgrade from 1.8 to 1.7 to make it work.

Ultimately this doesn't answer the question why the previous error pages were showing up despite the fact that all libraries were seemingly well imported and declared, i suspect the root of the problem to be lying in a compatibility issue between either tomcat or eclipse and the struts jars used, preventing the compiler from accessing the tld files and reading them.
At any rate what seems to appear clear through this is the inability of the server to deploy the tlds, the reason of this has yet to be defined.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but I dont have maven in the project.... I test tag tiles and struts and I have the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error as I  had a conflict between the jar files being added by me separately and additionally being called in the pom.xml. Make sure you depend only on one jar in a single way. I only added jars through maven (pom.xml)
[Maven Dependency jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJST1.jpg)